# How does one use python's __import__() and getattr() to correctly to instantiate nested classes?

Tags: python, python-import, instantiation, inner-classes

I have the following code in module xyz:

```
Class Outer:
   Class Nested:
       pass
```

I can successfully instantiate `Outer` objects as follows

```
module = __import__("xyz", fromlist=[''])
the_class = getattr(module, "Outer")
instance = the_class()
```

However, when I replace `"Outer"` with `"Outer.Nested"` I get:

`AttributeError: module 'xyz' has no attribute Outer.Nested`

How can one make this work?

I should perhaps clarify that the above code is being used to instantiate classes whose type is unknown until runtime. Obviously I am not looking for `instance = Outer.Nested()`.

Comment: So, just apply `getattr` twice, something like `outer, nested = "Outer.Nested".split('.'); klass = getattr(getattr(module, outer), nested)`

Comment: alternatively, use `operator.attrgetter` which will work with nested attribute access

Comment: @juanpa. Right on! Thanks so much. I just replaced the `getattr` line with `get_class = operator.attrgetter('Outer.Nested'); the_class = get_class(module)` and works great. I feel I should upvote and mark your answer as the correct answer. Will do so if you want to post an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways to do this, suppose you have a string representing attribute access and a nested object:

```
>>> from types import SimpleNamespace
>>> module = SimpleNamespace(foo=SimpleNamespace(bar=SimpleNamespace(baz='tada!')))
>>> module
namespace(foo=namespace(bar=namespace(baz='tada!')))
```

The first is to basically parse the string yourself by splitting and using `getattr` in a loop (or even, `reduce`!):

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> reduce(getattr, "foo.bar.baz".split('.'), module)
'tada!'
```

Which is just equivalent to:

```
>>> result = module
>>> for attr in "foo.bar.baz".split("."):
...     result = getattr(result, attr)
...
>>> result
'tada!'
```

Or use the built-in `functools.attrgetter` factory function as a one-off:

```
>>> import operator
>>> operator.attrgetter("foo.bar.baz")(module)
'tada!'
```

Answer (score 0):

To build on @juanpa.arrivillaga's answer (but explain why):

Classes and Modules are treated as objects in Python. So when you declare a class in a module, the class is an *attribute* of the module; and when you declare an inner class, the inner class is an *attribute* of the outer class *but not an attribute of the module*. When you are handing in `"Outer.Nested"` to the `getattr` of the module, you are asking for the *attribute of the module*, whereby there is a `.` *in the attribute's name*. Not quite the same thing as the attribute of an attribute. Python's interpreter would be doing the "attribute of an attribute" when it is parsing, hence why you got confused.

Answer (score 0):

By

> I should perhaps clarify that the above code is being used to instantiate classes whose type is unknown until runtime. Obviously I am not looking for `instance = Outer.Nested()`.
> do you mean that the name is not known until runtime? All *types* in Python are determined at runtime anyway.

If so, you could alternatively do a fancy, but common trick where a caller can hand in the type at runtime.

```py
# xyz.py
def get_instance(the_class):
  return the_class()
```

```py
# unknown_third_party
Class Outer:
   Class Nested:
       pass
```

```py
# main.py
from xyz import get_instance
import unknown_third_party
instance = get_instance(unknown_third_party.Outer.Nested)
```

You never need to know what is being handed in for your code to run--that is determined by your user/customer and at runtime.

Research Python's use of `@` for syntactic sugar to find out why this is so common.